# Twitter bootstrap flex vertical center does not work using align-self-center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am using twitter bootstrap 4.4.1 and flex to make a layout.
What I want to achieve is to have a navbar at the top and some content in the middle of the screen.

A bit like this:
[image]

I am using the following code (also jsfiddle here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oapLycqw/)):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="col-md-12 d-flex align-items-start justify-content-end">
            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-large">Large</button>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="row d-flex align-self-center">
            <div class="col-12 mx-auto">
                <div class="jumbotron text-center">
                    Some text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried a lot of things, but I just can't manage to get the text block centered on screen.

I am new to the layout/grid/flex system but it proves to be really difficult.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I have added class h-100 to make contianer of full height.
   `<div class="container h-100">`
2. You'll also need ensure any parent(s) are also 100% height (or have a defined height)...

   html,body {
   height: 100%;
   }
3. Use align-items-center instead align-self-center
   `<div class="row d-flex align-items-center h-100 m-auto">`

You can see the changes here as well [JSFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/2gxj4mhd/1/)

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="col-md-12 d-flex align-items-start justify-content-end">
            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-large">Large</button>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="row d-flex align-items-center h-100 m-auto">
            <div class="col-12 mx-auto">
                <div class="jumbotron text-center">
                    Some text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```